# IOS/Objective-C/Core-data: NSPredicate Filter by Date/Time

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I am trying to filter a fetch from Core Data by date using NSPredicate and am not getting the expected results.

This is how I set the date in core data:

```
 NSDate* currentDate = [NSDate date];
//create new managedobject and set value
 [record setValue:currentDate forKey:@"lasttouched"];
```

This is the predicate used to filter the fetch request from core data

```
 NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSDate *someTimeAgo = [now dateByAddingTimeInterval:-60*2]; // This is two minutes ago   
    NSPredicate *timePred=  [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"lasttouched <= %@", someTimeAgo];
```

//This logs to console as:
`lasttouched <= CAST(545096375.638440, "NSDate"`

I would expect the predicate to exclude from the fetch any managedobjects where the date in core data is more recent than 2 minutes before now.  However, it does not seem to be doing so.

Are there any issues with this code?  Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: In what way is it not working? How does it not work as expected?

Comment: you should use timestamps instead of dates.

Comment: Are you using the right comparison operator?  Shouldn’t it be >=, not <= ?

Comment: From your predicate: if lasttouched >= "now - 2 minutes", return the item. So it means that if the last touched occured between now and two minutes ago. While you want "to exclude from the fetch any managedobjects where the date in core data is more recent than 2 minutes before now". As said by @pbasdf, it seems to be reversed.